# AggregateMember inheritance: No handler was subscribed to command

Tags: axon

I have the below aggregate which contains an aggregate member.

```
@Aggregate
public class CpaAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String externalId;

    @AggregateMember
    private Entity entity;

    public CpaAggregate() {
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public CpaAggregate(CreateCpaCommand cmd) {
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new CpaCreatedEvent(...));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    protected void on(CpaCreatedEvent evt) {
      ....
    }

}

public class Entity {

    @EntityId
    private String entityId;
    
    private Set<Identifier> identifiers = new HashSet<>();

    public Entity() {
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(IdentifiantUpdatedEvent evt) {
        ...
    }
    
}

public class Laboratory extends Entity {

    private OperatingSystem operatingSystem;

    public Laboratory() {
    }
    
    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(UpdateIdentifierLABCommand cmd) {
       AggregateLifecycle.apply(new IdentifiantUpdatedEvent(....));
    }
    
}
```

.

```
commandGateway.sendAndWait(new UpdateIdentifierLABCommand(...));
```

When i send a command to update an identifier of entity of type laboratory, i get this error

> org.axonframework.commandhandling.NoHandlerForCommandException: No
> handler was subscribed to command [UpdateIdentifierLABCommand]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would model your `CpaAggregate` slightly differently, Aymen.

Instead of using the generic `Entity` aggregate member, I'd go for more specific entities like the `Laboratory` instance.

This is, for one, a lot more clear modeling-wise, as the model structure becomes clearer. Secondly, Axon Framework will move up into parent class for specifics. So, you can still have common information in an `Entity` class, like entity identifiers, command handlers, and event sourcing handlers.

I would thus adjust it like so:

```java
@Aggregate
public class CpaAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String externalId;

    @AggregateMember
    private Laboratory laboratory;

    public CpaAggregate() {
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public CpaAggregate(CreateCpaCommand cmd) {
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new CpaCreatedEvent(...));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    protected void on(CpaCreatedEvent evt) {
      ....
    }

}
```

This should ensure Axon Framework spots the command handler inside the aggregate member too, by the way.

Comment: thank you for your reply ^^ i have another issue about this, in the `Entity ` class i have the list `identifiers ` which is shared between all classes that inherit it. I want to add a new identifier to `Laboratory`, so i added the `@CommandHandler`  `CreateIdentifierLABCommand` in  the `Laboratory` class, and the `@EventSourcingHandler` `IdentifierCreatedEvent`  in the the `Entity ` class. The problem when i debug my code, It doesn't enter in the `@EventSourcingHandler`.  https://github.com/akanzari/axon/blob/main/test.java

Comment: Curious, this should simply work AFAIK. Can you write a test that consistently shows this fails and file a bug with Axon Framework? That'll allow the Framework dev's to further dig into this situation. https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/new/choose